# How to add DataGrid Widget into Listbox In Gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I want to create listbox.and when user clicks on that i want to display datagrid into dropdown.
private DataGrid objDataGrid;

```
public CallDataGrid() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public CallDataGrid(ArrayList<Student> objArrayList) {

    System.out.println("Datagrid is now going to set.");
    objDataGrid = new DataGrid<Student>();
    objLayoutPanel = new SimpleLayoutPanel();
    objScrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();

    objScrollPanel.add(objDataGrid);
    objLayoutPanel.add(objScrollPanel);

    objDataGrid.setEmptyTableWidget(new Label("There is no data to display."));

    final TextColumn<Student> nameColumn = new TextColumn<Student>() {
                         @Override
                         public String getValue(Student object) {
                                return object.getStrName();
                         }
    };
    objDataGrid.addColumn(nameColumn, "User Name");
    objDataGrid.setColumnWidth(nameColumn,100,Unit.PX);

    final TextColumn<Student> passwordColumn = new TextColumn<Student>() {
             @Override
             public String getValue(Student object) {
                return object.getStrPassword();
             }
      };
     objDataGrid.addColumn(passwordColumn, "Password");
     objDataGrid.setColumnWidth(passwordColumn,90,Unit.PX);

     objDataGrid.setWidth("190px");
     objDataGrid.setHeight("100px");

     objDataGrid.setRowData(0, objArrayList);
     objDataGrid.setPageSize(5);
```

// now how can i set this datagrid into Listbox or suggestion box??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No direct way to do what you want. Instead of a ListBox widget you can use a TextBox with a button on the right. When clicking the button put your DataGrid into a PopupPanel and display it by setting the its position on the bottom of the TextBox.